# STL unordered map with custom key type

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unordered-map

I have some graph-related C++ code that works using an `std::map` structure. I do not need the elements to be strictly ordered, and therefore I would like to switch to an `std::unordered_map` structure.

The relevant part of the code is as follows:

```
typedef unsigned size_type;

struct internal_edge{
 size_type node1_uid;
 size_type node2_uid;
};

std::map<size_type, internal_edge> edges_;
```

When I switch to `std::unordered_map`, the compiler complains of "too few template arguments for class template 'unordered_map'". I tried putting in a default hasher and comparator (**edit**: thanks @rems4e for the corrected version):

```
struct size_type_hash {
    std::size_t operator()(const size_type& k) const
    {
        return std::hash<size_type>()(k);
    }
};

struct size_type_equal {
    bool operator()(const size_type& lhs, const size_type& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs == rhs;
    }
};

std::unordered_map<size_type, internal_edge, size_type_hash, size_type_equal> edges_;
```

This still yields the same error message:

```
./Graph.hpp:384:9: error: too few template arguments for class template 'unordered_map'
   std::unordered_map<size_type, internal_edge, size_type_hash, size_type_equal> edges_;
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__hash_table:86:28: note: template is declared here
    class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS unordered_map;
                           ^
In file included from viewer.cpp:21:
./Graph.hpp:384:82: warning: private field 'edges_' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
   std::unordered_map<size_type, internal_edge, size_type_hash, size_type_equal> edges_;
```

My Makefile:

```
...
CXX := $(shell which clang++) -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11
...
```

And the output of `clang++`:

```
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

I am sort of stuck there, as this is one of my first excursions into the world of C++. Any ideas on how to make the unordered map constructor work?

Comment: It just works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c0c4386647fafae

Comment: How can `const size_type` be "aka `const unsigned int`" when you are referencing `size_type::first` and `size_type::second`? Looks like you think it's a pair.

Comment: Paste the full error message, and your compiler/version.

Comment: @louism Did you include `<unordered_map>`?

Comment: @T.C. Ugh! Didn't realize I had to include it. Why in the hell does it say the template is defined, then? Anyways, if you post that as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library headers can include each other in unspecified ways, and headers can also contain extra declarations, so the error (if any) you get when you forget to include a header isn't necessarily what you'd expect.

Here, for instance, one of the headers you included included the `<__hash_table>` internal header of libc++, which contains a *forward declaration* of `unordered_map`. This forward declaration contains no default template arguments (it can't have default arguments because the rules of the language prevents you from giving a template parameter default arguments in two declarations in the same scope, so if it did and then the user also included `<unordered_map>` - which must provide default arguments - the compiler would complain), so when the compiler sees you trying to use `unordered_map` with the default arguments, it complains that you have too few template arguments, rather than that `unordered_map` isn't declared.

If you actually passed the requisite number of template arguments, the compiler will probably complain instead that you are attempting to instantiate a template that's declared but not defined.

The fix is simple: include `<unordered_map>`. There's no need for a custom hasher or comparer either for `unsigned` - just use the default ones.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem probably comes from a bad copy-and-paste, as you are trying to get `first` and `second` fields from size_type variables, which are `typedef` to `unsigned int`.

Replace your hash functors by these and your code will compile:

```
struct size_type_hash {
    std::size_t operator()(const size_type& k) const
    {
        return std::hash<size_type>()(k);
    }
};

struct size_type_equal {
    bool operator()(const size_type& lhs, const size_type& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs == rhs;
    }
};
```

Just to be sure, do not forget to include the  header in your file.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. After making these modifications, the other errors are gone but I'm still stuck with "error: too few template arguments for class template 'unordered_map'"

Comment: The corrected code is perfectly compiled on my side. Are you sure you are giving us your working version? Which compiler are you using, and in which version?